# Copy entire rows that has unique value on Excel

Tags: excel, function

I have a table with several rows which may contain an equal value (specifically the product code) I have to create another table with a summary of the quantities of the products, so for example, if I have 3 identical products in table 1, in the summary table I only need to have one time that product code with a column that will show me quantity = 3 and the other columns must be filled in with the other product information, on google sheet I managed to do it with this formula: **=unique(query(scan!b5:j,"select b,c,d,e,f,g,h",1))**

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Iw7E.png)

how do I do this with excel functions?

Comment: Use `=UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(..........))`

Comment: I tried but I can’t make it work

Comment: Share few sample data and desired output. Also confirm you have access to CHOOSECOLS()` function. It is only available to office365 latest release.

Comment: You can see an example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Iw7E.png
I need to populate automatically the summary table